# How to run a windows service under non domain user account credentials

Tags: windows-services

I have a windows service which needs to be run under a different domain user account and not under my currently logged in domain account...is it possible to pass the domain credentials to the service?

I tried using 
Runas /netonly /user:domain\user "sc \localhost start ServiceName"

Comment: Can't you change the user on the [service's Log On tab](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-log-on-tab.jpg)?

Comment: From a batch file, use `sc config` to change the configuration.